# How to filter array from from build group

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an angular app where I have a list of users and a form with inputs, that are filtering the list. I am subscribed to the form group and when the value changes I am calling a filtering function that checks which inputs are active and then filter the array accordingly, but I think this is not the optimal way, because for now I am using only two filters and already I am checking 4 conditions and I want the form to have 5-6 filters and then the function will be much longer. Anyhow this is my function, can someone tell me how to make it work without the multiple conditions?

```
_filter(formData:{nameSearch:any, gameSearch:string}): void{
//here I am just declaring some variables
let nameStr = "";
let game = formData.gameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();   
let name = formData.nameSearch;
  if(typeof name === 'object'){
   nameStr = name.nickName.toLowerCase();
  }else{
   nameStr = name;
  }  

  if(nameStr.length !== 0 && game.length !== 0){ 
    this.filteredArr = this.usersArr.filter(user => {
      return (user.nickName).toLowerCase().includes(nameStr) && user[game] == true;
    })
  }
  if(nameStr.length !==0 && game.length === 0){
          this.filteredArr = this.usersArr.filter(user => {
            return (user.nickName).toLowerCase().includes(nameStr);
          })
    }
  if(nameStr.length === 0 && game.length !== 0 ){ 
    this.filteredArr = this.usersArr.filter(user => {
      return (user.nickName).toLowerCase().includes(nameStr) && user[game] == true;
    })
  }
  if(nameStr.length == 0 && game.length == 0){ 
    console.log('3');
     this.filteredArr = this.usersArr
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nameStr.length` check is superfluous because `.includes` will be `true` when any string is searched for the empty string.

The `game.length` and `user[game]` can be simplified by checking if `game.length` exists inside the filter callback, instead of making a separate `.filter`.

```
this.filteredArr = this.usersArr
    .filter(user =>
        user.nickName.toLowerCase().includes(nameStr) &&
        (!game.length || user[game])
    );
```

Comment: Yup, now it works as expected! Thanks a lot! How about if I want to add more filters? I suppose I just can attach them as you do with && and then check if they are active or true?

Comment: Yes, the same approach as `(!game.length || <gameCondition>)` should work.